# CSS iframe problem in IE 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have a page that looks perfectly at http://esolar.ca/calculator

But when I embed it into an iframe at http://esolar.ca/how-to-profit-from-microfit/microfit-income-calculator/

The Request An Assessment button in Internet Explorer 8 is too far to the left.  How do I make the contents of the iframe appear the same after it's been iframed?

Comment: Maybe IE thinks the window is too small. You can try to make it bigger and see if it works..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iFrame is overflowing in IE.  Changing the width to 584px "fixes" it for me.

Some things to reduce these kinds of problems:

1. Use a `DOCTYPE` to avoid triggering quirks mode in IE.  EG:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd">
   ```
2. Use a CSS reset to reduce cross-browser differences.  [Here's a good one](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css).
3. If all else fails, use [Conditional Comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) to tweak IE CSS.

Comment: Adding the DOCTYPE fixed the problem.  Thanks