# IE8 outright ignoring CSS styling

Tags: html, css, iframe

Let's say I have this CSS:

```
.tbl-div > h1 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: 10px -15px 30px -10px;
    padding: 0 0 0 40px;
}

.tbl-div > h1 > span {
    color: #006ec7;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

So let's say that there's this styling for a simple output div. The DOM for something like this would look as such

```
<div class="tbl-div">
  <h1>*title*<br><span>*subtitle*</span></h1>
  *content goes here*
</div>
```

The idea for the header section is that there is large text, then below it is a subtitle in smaller text and blue font. Here's the kicker. It actually works everywhere BUT an iframe. Once this goes into an iframe, the page just utterly thinks the CSS isn't there, and only in this case. It appears as a giant string of text 25px in font.

No other browser does this. And it's only with these properties, and only in an iframe.

What is happening?

Comment: Is your IE8 set to default to handle the security zone ? Seems like it is blocking the css file from being loaded into the iframe.

Comment: The CSS is being loaded in if developer tools are telling me anything.

It might just be prudent to handle putting inline styling if it's choosing to block only in this case of styling. The css and frame contents are on the same domain

Comment: Go to Tools->Internet Options -> Security tab, click "Reset all zones to default". And also try adding your own site to the trusted domains. Seems like IE is blocking the styles thinking its some kind of phishing attempt or something.

Comment: Have you set Doctype in your html? refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216491/css-iframe-problem-in-ie-8

Answer (score 0):

I checked it, working fine for me.
Make sure your document structure is proper. Then use **iframe** from another webpage like this:

```
<iframe src="file-containing-source.html"></iframe>
```

I made it here. See this: http://codepen.io/MustagheesButt/pen/RNXpEy